# Opencv: Invalid image when using BackgroundSubtractor

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

Here's the code:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread("recleft.jpg");
Mat procImg = new Mat();

BackgroundSubtractorMOG bs = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
bs.apply(img, procImg);

Highgui.imwrite("test.jpg", procImg);
```

However, when I open the `test.jpg` being produced by the program, it says "Invalid image". There is no direct tutorial I found regarding background subtractor using java and opencv. I based my code [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog#backgroundsubtractormog-backgroundsubtractormog)!.

I am currently creating a program which allow user to upload an image then get the background.

Comment: yes, the 1st image returned is empty. in general, it needs a couple of iterations to work properly. it's more useful on video, than on images

Comment: here is a nice tutorial: http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189

Comment: It works for me, even on first iteration with image.